# "As a patriotic person" or "a patriotic person"?

Tags: grammar

**A patriotic person**, he was dismayed that white people were taking over more and more of the Cherokee lands.

I wonder if "a patriotic person" in this sentence is correct. Or should it be changed to: "**As a patriotic person**, he was dismayed that white people were taking over more and more of the Cherokee lands."

Comment: The second provides better clarity. The first suffices grammatically, but sort of tests the comprehension of the listener

Comment: Yes, "A patriotic person" functions the same here as "As a patriotic person" or "Being a patriotic person". There might be *elision* there, but I'm not confident enough to give an answer.

Comment: Agreed, even a native speaker would possibly double take if they saw **A patriotic person, ...** . They might have to pause briefly before the meaning became obvious. This construct **is** used, but is far less common than **as** or **being**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can begin the sentence with **A patriotic person...**

There's nothing wrong with beginning the sentence this way. The part of the sentence that is doing the work is the clause:

> He was dismayed that white people were taking over more and more of
> the Cherokee lands.

The subject (the thing we're talking about) is **He**. The predicate (what we're saying of the subject) is everything else in the clause. The noun phrase **A patriotic person** is here an **adverbial** modifying the verb phrase **was dismayed**. That is, by saying "a patriotic person" we are describing in what character he was dismayed.